# Xubuntu 14.4 dual boot (windows 7) grub warning/problem

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, xubuntu

I installed **Xubuntu 14.4 LTS** ***dual boot*** with **Windows 7**. My hard disk is an **SSD disk** (where both xubuntu 14.4 and win7 are installed - in a different partition). I first installed Windows 7 and then I installed xubuntu. Xubuntu loads without errors/warnings. But when I try to choose Windows 7 from the grub I get the following warning/error:

```
setting partition type to 0x7
failing writing sector 0x0 to 'hd0'
```

Then asks to "press any key" and after a while Windows 7 boots without a problem. Why I have this warning/error? I tried to `$ sudo update-grub` inside xubuntu without any success.

update: this is my fstab and grub.cfg http://pastebin.com/vpbhLQLw

Comment: You can try boot-repair perhaps it will help or the log file gives some more info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for the above problem. My bios had a setting for "**Fixed disk boot sector**" and it was set at "**Write Protect**". I changed the option to "**Normal**" and the warning/error message disappeared!

[image: Bios settings for boot sector]